# Flutter legacy image should be converted warning

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

My app was running just fine until recently. In order to test something I replaced my `ABC` widget with `FlutterLogo` and started getting following error. I don't think I need to share the code, as it is of no use.

I removed `FlutterLogo` right after that, and replaced it with my original ABC widget, but the same error persist. However, both `flutter build apk` and `flutter build ios` are working just fine.

```
Exception processing event: Extension, {"type":"Event","kind":"Extension","extensionKind":"Flutter.RebuiltWidgets",
"isolate":{"type":"@Isolate","id":"isolates/185951910904495","name":"main","number":"185951910904495"},
"timestamp":1567424049962,"extensionData":{"startTime":0,"events":[1,1,2,1,42,1,43,1,44,1,45,1,57,1,58,1,60,1,62,
1,63,1,64,1,65,1,67,12,68,1,69,1,76,1,77,1,79,1,80,1,81,1,89,1,90,1,91,1,92,1,93,1,94,1,95,1,96,1,97,1,103,1,104,
1,105,1,106,1,107,1,108,1,109,1,110,1,111,1,112,1,113,1,115,1,121,1,122,1,125,1,127,1,129,1,131,1,132,5,133,5,134,
5,135,1,136,1,137,1,138,1,139,1,140,1,141,1,142,1,143,1,144,1,145,1,159,1,162,1,163,5,164,1,165,1,166,1,167,1,168,1,
169,1,170,1,171,1,180,1],"newLocations":{"file:///path_of_my_project/main.dart":[1,40,10,2,56,12,42,
109,13],"file:///path_of_my_project/home.dart":[43,635,12,44,652,14,45,659,13,57,665,21,58,704,
12,60,714,11,62,720,24,63,692,36,64,3874,12,65,3876,14,67,3928,12,68,3945,18,69,3947,20,76,3949,21,77,3902,13,79,3910,
132,80,4024,11,81,4027,20,89,4029,22,90,4045,11,91,4049,20,92,4052,22,93,2020,14,94,2023,16,95,2026,18,96,2117,7,97,
2119,18,103,2124,17,104,2145,23,105,2147,30,106,2149,36,107,2151,30,108,2153,36,109,2155,30,110,2157,36,111,2159,30,
112,2161,36,113,734,59,115,763,12,121,783,16,122,784,15,125,765,14,127,775,16,129,777,18,131,793,9,135,795,17,136,
809,9,137,810,17,138,846,9,139,847,17,140,850,9,141,885,17,142,891,9,143,892,17,144,900,12,145,902,14,159,909,19,
162,910,20,164,913,19,165,914,20,166,917,19,167,918,20,168,921,19,169,922,20,170,928,22,171,930,20,180,670,56],"
file:///path_of_my_project/file4.dart":[132,85,12,133,91,16,134,92,18,163,12,12]}}}
```

When I click on the file name, it shows me a dialog

[image]

Has anyone run into the same problem. I'm running Flutter `v1.9.6` and Android Studio `3.5`.

Note: I have't pulled anything from Github or some other source, it is my original project.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why but MacOS auto detect that dart file will open with DiskImageMounter by default
You can't fix this by changing the default application which will open dart file

- 2-finger click (or right click if you are using mouse) to any dart file
- Choose "Get Info"
- Under "Open With", expand the list and choose your default application, then click "Change All"
- Here the correct result image, the Open With section:[image]